# Why html_entities_decode is not decoding the html entities?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$string = "Perfect Valentine&#039;s Day Care Package | SpouseBuzz.com";
echo $string ."\n";
echo html_entity_decode($string) ."\n";
```

And it returns:

```
Perfect Valentine&#039;s Day Care Package | SpouseBuzz.com
Perfect Valentine&#039;s Day Care Package | SpouseBuzz.com
```

My question is: why html_entity_decode is not converting the html entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html_entity_decode()` by default will only convert double-quotes and will leave single-quotes alone. To also convert single-quotes to their corresponding character, add the [`ENT_QUOTES`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) flag:

```
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/107777)